# How can I move Picasa3 from one OSX machine to another without burning disks?

Tags: macos, picasa

I have all my pictures, captions, etc in Picasa3 on one OSX machine. I want to move everything to another OSX machine. How can I do that?

I'm aware of the "backup" feature (Tools -> Back Up Pictures), but it seems to only support burning disks, which seems wasteful in my case; these two machines are on the same network and I'm comfortable using `rsync` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you know where your pictures are located on your old computer. In picasa3, `File -> Add Folder To Picasa` shows you places it looks for pictures. In my case, I've set it to only use `~/Pictures`.
2. Copy pictures from the old computer to the new, using something like `caffeinate -i rsync -avz --progress me:oldcomp.local:Pictures ~/oldcomp_pictures`
3. Copy the Picasa3 database from the old computer to the new, using something like `caffeinate i- rsync -avz --progress "me:oldcomp.local:Library/Application\ Support/Google/Picasa3/db3" ~/oldcomp_db3`
4. Rename `~/Pictures` to `~/old_Pictures` and similarly set aside the existing db3 folder on the new computer
5. Rename the copied pictures and db folders to replace them
6. Open Picasa - everything should be there.

Note that copying the pictures may take a LONG time. If your WiFi is not the fanciest and newest kind, plugging both computers into the same router with Ethernet cable may speed things up dramatically. Using `caffeinate` will keep them from falling asleep during the process, assuming they don't drain their batteries; it's probably best to plug them in during the process.